# Meta-regression with metafor: Where has the variance gone?

Tags: r

I am wondering about the interpretation of the results of my meta analysis.

The set-up is very simlple: I have a dataset y that includes a variable TVAL (taken from a set of primary studies). TVAL is standardized so that its standard errors (the sampling standard errors from the primary studies) are 1 for all observations. SHORTREF is a factor representing the different primary studies.

I now perform a simple meta regression on a constant, using the metafor package:

```
> m<-rma.mv(yi=TVAL, V=1, random= ~ 1|SHORTREF, intercept=TRUE, method="REML", data=y)

> summary(m)

Multivariate Meta-Analysis Model (k = 933; method: REML)

    logLik    Deviance         AIC         BIC        AICc  
-3056.0316   6112.0633   6116.0633   6125.7379   6116.0762  

Variance Components: 

            estim    sqrt  nlvls  fixed    factor
sigma^2    6.6821  2.5850     84     no  SHORTREF

Test for Heterogeneity: 
Q(df = 932) = 8115.1664, p-val < .0001

Model Results:

estimate       se     zval     pval    ci.lb    ci.ub          
 -0.5544   0.2861  -1.9375   0.0527  -1.1151   0.0064        . 

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Residual heterogeneity (sigma^2) is 6.6821. Together with the sampling variance from the primary studies (which is 1 due to the standardization) I get a total variance of 6.6821 + 1 = 7.6821.
However, the total variance of my regressand TVAL is `var(y$TVAL)`=8.70726. That means, I am "missing" a part of my total variance which is neither sampling variance nor residual heterogeneity. This effect does not show up if I leave out the `1|SHORTREF` factor:

```
> m<-rma(yi=TVAL, sei=1, intercept=TRUE, method="REML", data=y)
> summary(m)

Random-Effects Model (k = 933; tau^2 estimator: REML)

    logLik    deviance         AIC         BIC        AICc  
-2330.9480   4661.8959   4665.8959   4675.5706   4665.9088  

tau^2 (estimated amount of total heterogeneity): 7.7073 (SE = 0.4034)
tau (square root of estimated tau^2 value):      2.7762
I^2 (total heterogeneity / total variability):   88.52%
H^2 (total variability / sampling variability):  8.71

Test for Heterogeneity: 
Q(df = 932) = 8115.1664, p-val < .0001

Model Results:

estimate       se     zval     pval    ci.lb    ci.ub          
 -0.5964   0.0966  -6.1731   <.0001  -0.7857  -0.4070      *** 

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Here, the residual heterogeneity tau^2 is the total variance `var(y$TVAL)`=8.70726 minus my sampling variance of 1.

Perhaps, it's really simple and I'm just not getting it, but any idea why in the first model (the one with the `1|SHORTREF` factor) not the full variance of TVAL is split into the assumed two error components (sampling and residual heterogeneity)?

Thanks! Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: Help with the interpretation of the results of a statistical model does not quality as a specific programming question. If you have questions about the application of statistical methods, you should ask your question on [stats.se] where statistical questions are on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three sources of variability here that you need to consider: Heterogeneity between studies, heterogeneity within studies, and sampling error. In your first model, you are neglecting the within-study heterogeneity. You should use something like this:

```
id <- 1:nrow(y)
m <- rma.mv(yi=TVAL, V=1, random= ~ 1|SHORTREF/id, data=y)
```

Note that the sum of the two variance components you get from this model (plus 1) will still not exactly add up to `var(TVAL)` because the decomposition isn't quite so simple. But you should then get something that closely matches the this variance. Here is an example with simulated data:

```
library(metafor)

k <- 100 ### total number of estimates
m <- 20  ### number of studies

vi <- rep(1, k)
id <- 1:k
study <- sort(sample(1:m, k, replace=TRUE))
yi <- rep(rnorm(length(unique(study)), 0, 2), times=table(study)) + rnorm(k, 0, 4)

var(yi)

res <- rma(yi, vi)
res$tau2 + 1

res <- rma.mv(yi, vi, random = ~ 1 | study/id)
sum(res$sigma2) + 1
```

Comment: Thanks, Wolfgang. One follow-up question if you don't mind: Do you know anything good to read to understand how the between-study variance estimator (the 1|study part) is calculated (either ML or REML)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to take a look at Konstantopoulos, S. (2011). Fixed effects and variance components estimation in three-level meta-analysis. Research Synthesis Methods, 2(1), 61-76.

Comment: Thanks, Wolfgang, that's very helpful.